# How to get a pointer to a COM method for hooking?

Tags: c++, winapi, assembly, activex, pointer-to-member

I know this seems like a over-answered question but this one is different.
I have this ActiveX object which exports some methods. I need to set a hook on one of its methods, namely `Func1`, I know how to do this by using `VirtualProtect()`, etc. If I open ollydbg and dig into the ActiveX DLL I see exactly the address of the `Func1` where I need to set the hook.

Using Visual Studio 2008, I am using the precompiler directive:

```
#import "myactx.dll" no_namespace, named_guids, raw_interfaces_only
```

And in my code I am trying to do this:

```
LPVOID ptr = &IMyActx::Func1;
```

which returns an error when compiling:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'HRESULT (__stdcall IMyActx::* )(BSTR,BSTR)' to 'LPVOID'.

I researched and found that I can't cast a pointer-to-class-method to a pointer-to-function because of the implicit **`this`** param.

However, I don't intend to call this function. I just want to know its address in memory so that I can pass it to my hooking routine (which expects a `LPVOID` pointer).

This seems inconceivable to me that I can call a function but not get its raw address in memory. It makes me want to insert some x86 assembly code just to get the pointer I want.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated, thanks for reading.

EDIT...
Now thinking of it... `LPVOID ptr = &IMyActx::Func1;` should not work because `IMyActx` is a pure virtual class! Anyway I tried some combinations before of instantiating an object and trying to get the raw pointer to `Func1` but nothing worked so far. I see in ollydbg that a call to `Func1` is generated as:

```
mov edx, [eax];
call dword ptr ds:[edx + 0x1C];
```

So I can assume I need to read the `DWORD` at `vptr + 0x1C` bytes and voilá.

If I recall correctly, the Component Object Model guarantees that it will always be the `Func1` ptr laying at `[vptr + 0x1C]` given the same Interface ID. forever. Right?

I will probably do something like this, in somewhat pseudo-code:

```
#define FUNC1_ENTRY   0x1C / sizeof(LPBYTE)

CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MyActx, 0, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMyActxObj, (LPVOID*) &pObj);

LPVOID pToHook = (*pObj)[FUNC1_ENTRY];
```

Comment: Pointer to methods and pointer to functions are not convertible as the standard does not guarantee (deliberately) that a method pointer can be stored in a void*. While a simple function pointer can be stored in a void*.

Comment: @Martin reinterpret_cast returns when compiling: `code` error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'HRESULT (__stdcall IMyActx::* )(BSTR,BSTR)' to 'LPVOID'
1>        There is no context in which this conversion is possible `code`

Comment: Sorry that was a spur of the moment though that I relized was wrong. I took it out because it should not work. (Note a method pointer may potentially be larger than a normal pointer. So it can not be converted into a void*).

Comment: The problem is not only in pointer size, but in ptm nature. What if it points to a virtual method of an abstract class, and call dispatches only when you provide this ;)? Pointers to members aren't "real" memory pointers at all...

Comment: The solution you have described in update should work, but looks pretty dangerous :)
Some years ago I've used detours to hook on activex objects.
I've just used ANSI C version of activex interfaces (you know, midl generates two versions in one file, one for C and one for C++).

Answer (score 1):

Methods of COM objects actually are ordinary functions.  That's what enables COM clients written in C instead of C++.

I recommend generating the header file for a C client, the function address will then be easily retrieved.  You do first need an instance of the class you intend to hook, however.

Comment: Methods of COM objects are *not* actually ordinary functions.  If you implement the object as a C++ class, there won't be any "regular" C functions.  Using the C-client header file, won't you just get the address of a stub method?  This might be enough for OP's purpose, however.

Comment: @Andre: They are ordinary C functions using the stdcall calling convention.  COM objects are nothing but a pointer to a structure of ordinary C function pointers.  That's what enables COM servers written in non-C++ languages.  Stubs are only involved for cross-process marshaling.  The fact that Visual C++, when virtual member functions are declared `__stdcall`, happens to generate a vtable matching the COM ABI is a happy coincidence (although of course intentionally achieved by the Visual C++ team)... all of COM is defined in terms of pure C.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to cast a pointer to a class method into a function pointer.

This actually is not possible.

Simple example:

```
class A {
    public:
    void func()
    {
        this->var = 0;
    }
    int var;
};

A myObj;
A::func* ptr2 = &(myObj::func); // works
void* ptr = &(myObj::func); // doesn't: what would "this" in line 5 point to?
```

You cannot even use `reinterpret_cast`.

Had this problem once, too. Then I simply had to create a function that maps the input value to a pointer to the object. Maybe you could create a wrapper function in which you call the method by having a pointer to it?

Comment: The story changes when the `__stdcall` calling convention is in use, as it is for all COM object methods.  A class member function using stdcall is a normal function with `this` as the first parameter.  (This isn't true of member functions using the default `__thiscall` calling convention.)

Comment: Now, you're correct that a pointer-to-member-function still is not the same as a function pointer even when the member function is an ordinary `__stdcall` function.  In fact, I don't think there is a simple syntax for getting a normal function pointer, one can either read the vtable or take the address of the function by its mangled name.